# Handles return empty

Tags: matlab-guide

Good morning 
I need to show images (one at a time) in a Axis in my GUI when click in the submenu "open".
When I click for first time it´s working, but, from the second time appears a error:

ERROR => hAxesImagem =  Empty matrix: 0-by-1

i.e, I find a handle in first time run, but from the second time not.

I tried to use findall too...

my code:

```
 hAxesImagem = findobj('Tag','AxesImagem')
 handles = guidata(hAxesImagem)
 cla(handles.AxesImagem,'reset')
 axes(handles.AxesImagem);
```

Answer (score 0):

it´s working

```
    object_handles = findall(gca);
    hAxesImagem = findall(object_handles,'Type','axes');
    handles = guidata(hAxesImagem);
    cla(handles.AxesImagem,'reset');
    axes(handles.AxesImagem);
```